# Translation with reactions not working on python

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to do a bot translation using reactions. Although something is not working.

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_reaction_add(self, reaction, user):

    if user == self.client:
        return

    if reaction.emoji == ":flag_us:":
        text = reaction.message.id
        translate_text = google_translator.translate(text, lang_tgt='en')
        await self.client.send_message(translate_text.channel)
    elif reaction.emoji == ":flag_cn:":
        text = reaction.message.id
        translate_text = google_translator.translate(text, lang_tgt='zh')
        await self.client.send_message(translate_text.channel)
    else:
        return
```

No error returned and no action made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because [`reaction.emoji`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#emoji) isn't a string, but is an object itself. You're probably looking for `reaction.emoji.name`.

Also, there are a few issues within the `if`/`elif` clauses that would prevent your code from running, even if the original issue was fixed.

1. `reaction.message.id` is an integer, so passing it to `google_translator.translate()` will result in an error.
2. The name of an emoji tends not to be the name you would enter in Discord. The best practice would be to put the unicode of the emoji.
3. To send a message to channel, you should use [`TextChannel.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.send)

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
    if payload.member == self.client:
        return
    if payload.emoji.name == u"\U0001f1fa\U0001f1f8":
        message = await self.client.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
        translate_text = google_translator.translate(message.content, lang_tgt='en')
        channel = await self.client.fetch_channel(payload.channel_id)
        await channel.send(translate_text)
    elif payload.emoji.name == u"\U0001F1E8\U0001F1F3":
        message = await self.client.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
        translate_text = google_translator.translate(message.content, lang_tgt='zh')
        channel = await self.client.fetch_channel(payload.channel_id)
        await channel.send(translate_text)
```

This would work, but I would recommend taking all of the various calls *outside* of the `if`/`elif` clauses:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
    if payload.member == self.client:
        return

    emoji_to_language = {
        u"\U0001f1fa\U0001f1f8": "en",
        u"\U0001F1E8\U0001F1F3": "zh"
    }
    lang = emoji_to_language.get(payload.emoji.name)
    if lang is None:
        break
    message = await self.client.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    translate_text = google_translator.translate(message.content, lang_tgt=lang')
    channel = await self.client.fetch_channel(payload.channel_id)
    await channel.send(translate_text)
```

Comment: an error as return - TypeError: on_raw_reaction_add() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: @DuarteRita Oops, I forgot about `self`.

Comment: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'fetch_message'

Comment: Do I need to use:channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)

Comment: it worked with 
```             channel = self.client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
            message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
            translate_text = google_translator.translate(message.content, lang_tgt='en')
            channel = await self.client.fetch_channel(payload.channel_id)
            await channel.send(translate_text) ```
The second code was giving alot of errors.

Comment: Oh, I wasn’t sure if you were using a `Bot` or a `Client` instance, and I assumed `Client` because your variable name was `client`.